# Converting Python output to PDF

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf

I was working on a mini project and it involves me writing code to determine the mean, median, mode and range as the first stage (which I was successfully able to do). The second and final stage is to convert the output into a PDF file. I do not know how to do this, and hence, this was the code I could successfully run. Other than the converter, I had no problems using this code to find the output of my mean, median, mode and range.

> ## For working out the mean:
>
> ```
> def mean(numbers):
>     return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)
> ```
>
> ## For working out the median:
>
> ```
> def median(lst):
>    lst = sorted(lst)
>    if len(lst) < 1:
>        return None
>    if len(lst) %2 == 1:
>        return lst[((len(lst)+1)/2)-1]
>    else:
>        return float(sum(lst[(len(lst)/2)-1:(len(lst)/2+1)]))/2.0
> ```
>
> ## For working out the mode:
>
> ```
> def mode(array):
>     most = max(list(map(array.count, array)))
>     return list(set(filter(lambda x: array.count(x) == most, array)))
> ```
>
> ## For working out the range:
>
> ```
> def getrange(val_list):
>     min_val = min(val_list)
>     max_val = max(val_list)
>
>     return (max_val - min_val)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This package looks pretty good:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfdocument

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/pythondoc-pyPdf.pdf.html), especially the PdfFileWriter() class to do the same